# How to enforcing Laravel to render view components on a string?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9, laravel-view-component

I have this string:

```html
<div class="my-card-container">
  <x-card :title="Hello Wordl"></x-card>
</div>
```

This string is coming from database, it lives in the `Conent` model's `html` property. I use it in my `ContentController` like this:

```php
    public function serve(Request $request, string $uri = ''): View
    {
        $content = Content::whereUri($uri);

        return view('main', [
            'content' => $content->html,
        ]);
    }
```

In my `main.blade.php`:

```html
@section('content')
<main>
    @include('main.content')
</main>
@stop
```

I want to render any available view components on my string.

Can I somehow enforce Laravel to apply the `CardComponent` **or any other available component** on that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blade::render() will help you.

Try this:

```php
    public function serve(Request $request, string $uri = ''): View
    {
        $content = Content::whereUri($uri);

        $content = Blade::render($content);

        return view('main', [
            'content' => $content->html,
        ]);
    }
```